# Vue.Js draw lines between components problem

Tags: vue.js, svg

I am using SVGs to draw lines between components that are related in my app.   Currently I am grabbing those elements and getting their position info with document.getElementById() and then using getClientBoundingRect.

This generally works, but there is occasional render wonkiness.

Is there a better way to do this?  Perhaps an already existing library that works with VueJs?

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question so we can see. And although you know what wonkiness means, we don't so some screenshots would help there as would exact steps to reproduce it and affected browsers. If only one browser is affected then create a bugreport in its bugtracker.

Comment: @RobertLongson I’m away from my computer this second.  I’ll add code and screenshots later.  Essentially I’ve been drawing lines between 2 components.  As the page resides and adjusts, i watch the positions of the components with a timer, and make sure the lines are accurately drawn.  All is well up to this point.  Once I start modifying properties on the component (isSelected) it loses the rectCoordinate from the dom for some reason.

Comment: I created this code pen to simulate my situation.  It's very crude, but it gets the point across.

Comment: @RobertLongson Click the red square on the top left.  I'm only changing the class, and it re renders and doesn't show the line.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aedgyx?editors=0001

Answer (score 0):

Changing the class puts a CSS filter on the shape because you have

```
.isSelected {
    filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

Now the [W3C Filter Effects spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#FilterProperty) says

> The application of the ‘filter’ property to an element formatted with the CSS box model establishes a new stacking context the same way that CSS ‘opacity’ does, and all the element's descendants are rendered together as a group with the filter effect applied to the group as a whole.

So browsers are doing the correct thing per that specification. The new stacking context puts the shape in front of the line.

See also [this wontfixed Chromium bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154671)

Comment: Even if i don't modify a CSS or style property, this actually still happens.  I know it has something to do with the VueJS render engine.  So what im looking for is tips as to controlling render order, or a library that already exists that does what I need here

Comment: I removed the filter in the DOM inspector and the top left square returned to below the line.

Comment: Robert, I think that's because code-pen doesn't run the package manager version of vue from the CLI.

that was the closest i could get to show my example, so the behavior may be a little different

Comment: I can only really comment on the testcase you provide though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being because of `document.getElementById` and z-order

I ended up changing my timer to get the element by ref, and iterate through the children of my component to find it.

Here is the code:

```
 drawLines: function () {
    let children = this.$children
    let lines = this.lines
    lines.splice(0, lines.length)

    let scheduleContainer = this.$refs.scheduleContainer
    let scheduleContainerRect = scheduleContainer.getBoundingClientRect();

    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      let child = children[i]

      if (child.$props.assignment) {
        if (child.$props.assignment.assignmentRequestId != "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") {
          for (let ii = 0; ii < children.length; ii++) {
            let child2 = children[ii]
            if (child2.$props.assignmentRequest) {
              if (child2.$props.assignmentRequest.id == child.$props.assignment.assignmentRequestId) {
                let assignmentRect = child.$refs.theContainer.getBoundingClientRect()
                let requestRect = child2.$refs.theContainer.getBoundingClientRect()
                 let x1 = ((assignmentRect.left - scheduleContainerRect.left) + 12.5) + 'px'
                 let y1 = ((assignmentRect.top - scheduleContainerRect.top) + 12.5) + 'px'
                 let x2 = ((requestRect.left - scheduleContainerRect.left) + 12.5) + 'px'
                 let y2 = ((requestRect.top - scheduleContainerRect.top) + 12.5) + 'px'
                 let line = { 'x1': x1, 'y1': y1, 'x2': x2, 'y2': y2 }              
                 lines.push(line)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```